Local Outlier Factor for time series
I hope this makes sense. I have discovered LOF and tried it in R. However, since I am dealing with time series, the neighbors cannot be "future" neighbors of the current observation(s). I am wondering if using LOF to detect outliers in a time series can be a problem because of this. Basically, given a one-dimensional dataset sorted by date, I'd like LOF to give a factor considering only the neighbors on the left of the current observation, not on the right.
What I am trying is finding anomalies in my time series. Anomalies being a value in the time series that is very unexpected given (only) the previous values of the series.
EDIT
Giving more context of my goal.
I would like to develop a method to identify anomalies in a continuous time series with monthly frequency, with the scope of understanding, as new data are acquired, if the new record is an anomaly or not (a sort of Early Warning system).
What I am focusing on at the moment, is finding a method that could identify the anomalies which have already occurred, by applying it to my historical data and see how it works.
I am combining different methodologies: LOF is one of these, then I am using K-means to divide my data into 3 groups and then calculating the modified z-score on these groups. I apply some thresholds to these calculated indicators to mark the outliers in my series.
I also do some ex-post adjustment to 1) add new outliers to the list if the current class has a cluster-centroid which is different then the previous one (because we have entered a new "regime"); 2) remove the outliers from the list if the previous observation was already marked as outlier (because we are only interested to receive a warning at the beginning of an anomalous phase).
As new observations come in, I am unsure on how to proceed, but one idea would be to re-run the entire process (not a big effort, the data is pretty small). Another idea I had was to predict the future new observation by constructing a predictive model with the anomalies being my target value, but I would probably need information which I would still need to calculate at the time of making the predictions, so I think it does not make mush sense.

Hm. I would not categorically say that "future" values cannot be used. If you want to cleanse your historical data prior to modeling, then I would say that looking at both sides makes perfect sense. If you want to check the last data point, then of course you can't use the future value. Can you tell us what you plan on doing after you have detected "outliers"? (And also, often the best course of action is to understand and model such anomalous points, see my examples here.)

Thanks for the comment @StephanKolassa I am trying to detect anomalies in my time series. What is puzzling me, is that I'd like LOF not to consider the local deviation from values that have not already occurred. If I am considering Xt, and I want to use 5 neighbors, I'd like to use Xt-4 to Xt, rather than having my Xt being the central value in time. This is because I would be interested to see if its local deviation is far from what already happened, not from what still needs to happen. In a nutshell: I need to understand if it Xt is a new outlier of the time series, not an historical outlier

I have edited my question to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Is the goal to predict anomalies before they occur? Saying more about your overall goals will be helpful, as I can see arguments for and against using future values, depending on what you want to do.

I have added a description of the goal. No, for now I am not interested in identifying anomalies BEFORE they occur, but, as new data are available, I want to be able to understand if a new anomaly has occurred.

Then don't you get to use all available information?

I think I understood. The problem is I am trying to validate the historical values, but I should reason in terms of "last point in the series". Indeed, I should use all previous information:)

I will update my question/answer my own question to reflect this reasoning as soon as I can. Indeed, posing the problem and reasoning about your comments made me realise what's the answer, thanks.

Splendid! It's perfectly within the etiquette here to post a self-answer. I have done this multiple times. I look forward to reading what you post.

Thanks to the comments I received in my question, I have realized that I should not be worried about the directionality of the LOF, since I will be using it to find if new data are anomalous. Therefore, if I want to validate my anomaly detection algorithm using historical data, the reasoning would be that I decide which point in my series I want to test and that I will trim the time series up to this very same point. Then I would run my algorithm with the aim to knowing whether this last point is an anomaly or not. This reasoning of considering only the last point of the series means that I am automatically going to use only its previous neighbors to calculate its LOF, because there should not be any point beyond this, as it should be in the actual use case.
I guess my original doubt is still relevant if we assume we can calculate the LOF on historical data to evaluate points that are not the last one in the series. It should not be used in this situation I guess, because they would have neighbors that in a real use case would not be happened yet, and therefore it might be biased.
